# Two sorting rules in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy

With the following code:

```
<g:each in="${books.sort{it.date}}" status="i" var="book"> 
    ${book}
</g:each>
```

I want to display the books to be sorted by date; additionally, I want the books authored by the person currently logged in to show up first.

Is that possible?

Comment: What you are trying to do is not sorting but a combination of sorting (on basis of date) and priority(for logged in user records). Reason for saying that is how will you assure ordering then. Could you please give an example of input and output.Do you want all logged in author records on top irrespective of date or records should still be sorted by date but first record for a particular date should be logged in author's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you want to achieve but you can do this. Before passing your `books` list to your GSP, you can write like this:

```
def myAction() {
     List books = Book.list()  // Get your book list

     User loggedInUser = User.first()  // Get your currently logged in user

     // First get all the books of current user sorted by the date
     List currentUsersBooks = books.findAll { it.author.id == loggedInUser.id }.sort{ it.date }

     // Then get other books sorted by date
     List otherBooks = books.findAll { it.author.id != loggedInUser.id }.sort{ it.date }

     // Now merge all of them (as `List` will maintain insertion order)
     // So current user's book will be listed first and then others
     List allBooks = currentUsersBooks + otherBooks

     [books: allBooks]
}
```

Now, modify your GSP to do not sort again:

```
<g:each in="${books}" status="i" var="book"> 
   ${book}
</g:each>
```

Considering, the `Book` and `User` domain class like this:

```
class User {
     String email
}

class Book {
     Strig title
     User author
}
```